# How is the “quality scale” defined in the journal Frontiers in Oncology?

Tags: peer-review

After submitting my manuscript to Frontiers in Oncology, I recently received feedback. The comments were overall minor, but I am concerned about the quality assessment provided at the end:

> **QUALITY ASSESSMENT:** 
>     Rigor: 2
>     Quality of the writing: 2
>     Overall quality of the content: 2
>     Interest to a general audience: 2

I am curious about the scoring scale used by Frontiers in Oncology for peer review. Does anyone know how this scale is defined or what these scores indicate about my manuscript?

Comment: Perhaps rating 1 is "outstanding", so 2 is "not bad at all" ??  I wonder how far down the scale goes.

Answer (score 4):

I have a paper published in Frontiers in Oncology. Each reviewer provided a Quality Assessment like this:

[image]

They use a 5-level scale which is ordered from  1 (lowest) to  5 (highest) quality, inferred based on my paper positive comments and outcome. I checked the [available guidelines](https://www.frontiersin.org/design/pdf/re_guidelines.pdf) for Frontiers' reviewers, but they do not mention this scale. I also couldn't find anything about these scales on their website.

Comment: I was also just looking, and found a similar (physics) paper that I also would have suggested 5 is the good end of the scale.